# How to parallel loop two sets of columns in pandas df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to parallel loop two lists of columns in pandas df? For example, I need to create C1=A1 + B2, C2=A2+B2, C3=A3+B3...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6),
           columns=['A1', 'A2', 'A3','B1', 'B2','B3'])

    A1          A2          A3          B1          B2          B3
0   -0.045858   0.627827    -1.562130   2.094783    0.654119    -0.996711
1   1.003585    0.735500    0.795338    -0.803864   -0.071655   -0.514118
2   0.083501    0.774820    -1.477767   -1.260052   0.861952    -0.674270
```

Comment: Desired output is a list or another pandas frame, please mention...

Comment: whats wrong with exactly what you typed? `C1=df['A1']+df['B2']`,`C2=df['A2']+df['B2']`,etc? i imagine the overhead of making threads/processes to act in parallel exceeds any benefit they provide for something like this ... how big is your df in reality?

Comment: with 3 million entries on my not that fast pc it take 0.03 seconds to `df['A1'] + df['B1']`

Comment: The example is simple. The real data involves a lot more sets of calculation and more complicated calculation. You don't want to type df['A1'] + df['B1'] 100 times.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `groupby` with `axis=1`:

```
>>> df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.str[1:], axis=1).sum().add_prefix('C'))
         A1        A2        A3        B1        B2        B3        C1        C2        C3
0 -0.207101 -2.051288  1.080908  1.431754  2.585950 -0.840431  1.224653  0.534661  0.240476
1  0.800892 -0.180519  0.111748  2.057722  1.710686  0.617960  2.858614  1.530167  0.729708
2 -0.603030 -0.859876 -1.275922 -2.043422  1.162243  0.223720 -2.646451  0.302366 -1.052203
>>>
```

Or if you might have different legth'ed prefixes and numbers, try:

```
df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)$'), axis=1).sum().add_prefix('C'))
```

Comment: Good approach. Just to note: the assumption with this implementation is that all number suffixes are a single digit.

Comment: @HenryEcker Edited my answer

Comment: I'd use `df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)$')`

Comment: I wasn't saying it was wrong. :) I was just stating the assumption that was made. Because now we've made the assumption that the prefix is a single letter. Which is fine for the provided sample but may need modified depending on the actual columns.

Comment: @QuangHoang Good idea

Comment: @QuangHoang Edited mine

Comment: Smart !  I didn't know can group by columns !  Learnt something

Comment: @EBDS Yeah! It's a very useful feature :) Using `axis=1` solves everything :P

Comment: @U12-Forward What would you do if the calculation is complicated, e.g., C1=A1+ A1*B1?

Comment: @ponderwonder Use `df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.str[1:], axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 0] + x.iloc[:, 0] * x.iloc[:, 1]).add_prefix('C'))`.